# how can I use dpkg to install a deb file for all users

Tags: ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu pc and I'm trying to install a program using a deb file.
can I install this program using dpkg for all the users on the system?

at the end I want all the users to be able to use this program.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs installed using `sudo dpkg -i package-file` should be installed globally and will be available to all users. To install a .deb file named package-file.deb in Ubuntu, open the terminal and type:

```
cd /path/to/directory/containing/package-file.deb
sudo dpkg -i package-file.deb
```

To display a verbose description of how `dpkg -i` works in Ubuntu, run this command in the terminal:

```
LESS='+/^[[:space:]]*-i' man dpkg
```